# Windows boot manager not showing up

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-server-2012-r2

I had Windows 10 installed in my pc. And I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 in another partition so I can dual boot it.

But when I start my pc Windows boot manager doesn't show up and it boots into Windows 10. But when I'm doing a restart then the boot manager shows up. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Disable `Fast Boot` in `Power Options` > `Choose what power buttons do`

Comment: I tried it but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .. I installed Windows Server 2012 r2 at last. so it replaced the Windows 10 boot loader. So I repaired dual boot by VisualBCD.. it solved the problem. now I get the Windows 10 metro boot manager..